# How I can do a regex split in group value?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a regex split but my code does not work.

I don't know how correct this.

```
string input = "code1,code2,#c55+G35+G97#g,coden,code3,code4,#c44+A25+A07#gcoden";

string output = Regex.Replace(
     input,
     "#c(.*?)#g",
      m => m.Groups[1].Value 
         + m.Groups[2].Value.Regex.Split(@"+\w").Sum(v => int.Parse(v)) + "#" );
```

`+\w` matches "+A" and "+G"

My error is thrown on this line: `m => m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value.Regex.Split(@"+\w").Sum(v => int.Parse(v)) + "#" );`

ERROR

> 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' does not contain a definition for 'Regex' and no extension method 'Regex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) -

ERROR2

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type (CS1660)

How can I use a regex split?

THIS IS my desired output

code1,code2,#c55+35+97#g187#,coden,code3,code4,#c44+25+07#g76#coden

please help me

Comment: First error seems clear - `m.Groups[2].Regex` is invalid. Did you mean `m.Groups[2].Value`?

Comment: yes i mean this

Comment: Sorry. Bad rollback. My mistake. Fixed.

Comment: ok no problem , thanks

Comment: Also, one issue is that `Value` is a string and string has no Regex property. You need to: `Regex.Split(m.Groups[2].Value, @"+\w")`

Comment: @jhonny625 would you be so kind to explain what the desired result is of `output` ?

Comment: this is code1,code2,#c55+35+97#g187#,coden,code3,code4,#c44+25+07#g76#coden

Comment: @jhonny625 thank you

Comment: i need use regex split because that allows you to use more options when selecting

Comment: thanks for your answer  Johnny Mopp I solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 using System;

     using System.Text;
        using System.IO;
           using System.Linq;

     using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   class Program


   {

     static void Main()

     {

        string input =   "code1,code2,#c55+G35+G97#g,coden,code3,code4,#c44+A25+A07#gcoden";

  string output = Regex.Replace(
    input,
    "(#c(.*?)#g)",
    m => m.Groups[1].Value + Regex.Split(m.Groups[2].Value, @"\+\w").Sum(v => int.Parse(v)) + "#" );
 Console.WriteLine(output);



  }
      }
```

thanks for your answer Johnny Mopp